# ASSIGNED or AGGREGATED-BY-LIR status of IPv6 subnet used for Virtualisation

Tags: subnet, ipv6

According to the RIPE NCC IPv6 Basics training slides the `ASSIGNED` status should be used for your own infrastructure and individual (large) assignments to customers. The `AGGREGATED-BY-LIR` status should be used for sub-assignments to multiple customers, and multiple /56 registered as subnets of one /48 is given as example.

How would I register an IPv6 subnet to be used for virtualisation? The host nodes are my infrastructure, but each virtual server running on those nodes belongs to a customer which gets a /64 assigned to its virtual server. Should I setup that /48 subnet used for virtualisation as `ASSIGNED` to me (as its my infrastructure with just my routers) or should this become a `AGGREGATED-BY-LIR` with an assignment size of 64 (as its basically sub-assignments even when they are all running within my network)?

Comment: Are you a a Local Internet Registry?

Comment: Yes, I'm acting as a RIPE NCC LIR.

Comment: That is then your answer. Really, you should verify with RIPE, but you would have an assigned network, and you would be assigning individual subnets from that as aggregated to your assigned network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't thought about that earlier, but I just looked up how some of the well-known hosting providers (to be specific, I checked OVH and Hetzner) setup their IPv6 customer subnets: they all chose to go with the `AGGREGATED-BY-LIR` for their customer subnets. So, I guess that's the way to go.